# The set $C=\{(x,y,z,t)\in\mathbb{R}^4\mid x^2+y^2+z^2=t^2\}$ is closed

Tags: general-topology

The proof I've attempted at is the following:

Suppose that $\mathrm{int}C\neq \varnothing$. So let $(a,b,c,d)\in \mathrm{int}C$. Then by the definition of interior point, $\exists \delta>0$ such that $B((a,b,c,d); \delta)\subset C$.

But note that $(a,b,c+\delta,d)$ is an element of $B((a,b,c,d);\delta)$ that is not in $C$ since $(a,b,c,d)\in C$ so $a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2$ and thus $a^2+b^2+(c+\delta)^2>d^2$ for $\delta>0$. Then $B(a;\delta)\not\subset C$ which is a contradiction so $\mathrm{int}C=\varnothing$.

So the boundary of $C$ must equal $C$ hence $\mathrm{cl}(C)=C$ and $C$ is closed.

Is this proof correct? What's a better way to show this? I tried to directly show that any ball around any point in $C$ would contain another point of $C$ and a point of the exterior but I couldn't figure out coordinates for a point not equal to center in the ball satisfying the equation of $C$.

Comment: What does int(C) being empty have to do with whether C is closed?

Comment: The interior being empty does not imply that the boundary is $C.$ For example, the  set $D=\{(a,b,c,d)\in C\mid d>0\}$ has empty interior, but its boundary is not $D.$

Comment: No, there are plenty of sets without interiors that aren't closed (the set of rationals as a subset of the reals as an example). You have to show that, for any point outside of C, there's some neighbourhood around it that is still outside of C. Alternatively, since your space is metric, you can just show that any sequence in $C$ that has a limit has its limit in $C$. Either way, $C$ having an empty interrior is irrelevant, and I do not immediately know of any theorems that would make it relevant.

Comment: A subset is equal to its boundary if and only if it is **both** closed **and** has an empty interior.

Comment: Also, the name for $C$ is a higher-dimensional cone (or rather, two cones, one with $t \ge 0$ and the other with $t \le 0$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know what continuous functions are, then you may notice that there is a map $f:\mathbb{R}^4\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y,z,t)=x^2+y^2+z^2-t^2$, it's a polynomial in $x,y,z,t$ hence it is continuous. This gives you that preimage of closed sets by $f$ are closed. Then maybe you can manage to express your set as $f^{-1}(S)$ for some closed set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}$, in which case you'll know your set $C$ is closed.

Also, as it stands, your proof is not correct, a set may very well have empty interior while not being closed, as you can see in the comments.